# Parsing a CSV file using gawk

Tags: bash, csv, awk, gawk

How do you parse a CSV file using gawk?  Simply setting `FS=","` is not enough, as a quoted field with a comma inside will be treated as multiple fields.

Example using `FS=","` which does not work:

file contents:

```
one,two,"three, four",five
"six, seven",eight,"nine"
```

gawk script:

```
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "field #%d: %s\n", i, $(i)
  printf "---------------------------\n"
}
```

bad output:

```
field #1: one
field #2: two
field #3: "three
field #4:  four"
field #5: five
---------------------------
field #1: "six
field #2:  seven"
field #3: eight
field #4: "nine"
---------------------------
```

desired output:

```
field #1: one
field #2: two
field #3: "three, four"
field #4: five
---------------------------
field #1: "six, seven"
field #2: eight
field #3: "nine"
---------------------------
```

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is "I wouldn't use gawk to parse CSV if the CSV contains awkward data", where 'awkward' means things like commas in the CSV field data.

The next question is "What other processing are you going to be doing", since that will influence what alternatives you use.

I'd probably use Perl and the Text::CSV or Text::CSV_XS modules to read and process the data.  Remember, Perl was originally written in part as an `awk` and `sed` killer - hence the `a2p` and `s2p` programs still distributed with Perl which convert `awk` and `sed` scripts (respectively) into Perl.

Comment: See also the [`csvfix`](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/) program.  Of course, Python (and Ruby, and Tcl, and most other extensible scripting languages) can be used instead of Perl; that becomes a question of personal taste or company-mandated (Hobson's) choice.

Comment: I went down the `gawk` use `FPAT` path for the past hour.  It can not cope with many real world situations like empty fields and double quotes within fields as pointed out.  Time to switch to something more powerful!

Comment: frawk is a better fit than perl if you don't specifically want to write perl here and know awk

Comment: @saolof — It would be helpful to provide a link to frawk, and a brief explanation of why it can handle CSV.  I note that [One True Awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk) has an option for handling CSV directly.  The world has changed a bit since 2008, but an awful lot of things are remarkably similar too.

Comment: Ah, frawk is basically an AWK-like dialect that happens to have built-in support for CSV: https://github.com/ezrosent/frawk

It has the pro and the con of changing AWK slightly for the sake of making it efficiently compilable (and parallelizable if no variables live longer than a row), so that it ends up being very fast when processing large CSV files and gives much better error messages. Most of book AWK still runs on it but it is extended differently than nawk and gawk with a slightly less dynamic interpretation of the spec

Comment: For most people just using a widely used posix AWK is the option I would suggest though. I would just advise against Perl, partly because of the risks of backtracking regexes, but also because AWK dialects have aged a lot better and AWK has a clearer scope for when you should move to a different tool

Answer (score 16):

[The gawk version 4 manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) says to use `FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"`

When `FPAT` is defined, it disables `FS` and specifies fields by content instead of by separator.

Comment: The FPAT concept is interesting.  The regex quoted though does not allow for double quotes within the quoted string.  That requires a more complex regex, such as: `FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")+\"[^,]*)"`.  The final `[^,]*` allows for malformed fields which start with quotes, such as `"abc"def,`; it treats the `def` as part of the field.  Within the double quotes, two consecutive double quotes are accepted.  This stuff is _nasty_, which is why CSV-specific modules are usually the best way to deal with CSV data unless the CSV data is clean and simple.

Comment: FPAT requires gawk 4. Took me some time... ;)

Comment: I've set up an alias with gawk to make it easy to run gawk on CSVS:

`alias awkcsv="gawk -v FPAT='([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")'"`

Answer (score 4):

If permissible, I would use the Python [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, paying special attention to the [dialect used and formatting parameters required](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters), to parse the CSV file you have.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple wrapper function called csvquote to sanitize the input and restore it after awk is done processing it. Pipe your data through it at the start and end, and everything should work out ok:

before:

```
gawk -f mypgoram.awk input.csv
```

after:

```
csvquote input.csv | gawk -f mypgoram.awk | csvquote -u
```

See https://github.com/dbro/csvquote for code and documentation.

Answer (score 2):

#### csv2delim.awk

```
# csv2delim.awk converts comma delimited files with optional quotes to delim separated file
#     delim can be any character, defaults to tab
# assumes no repl characters in text, any delim in line converts to repl
#     repl can be any character, defaults to ~
# changes two consecutive quotes within quotes to '

# usage: gawk -f csv2delim.awk [-v delim=d] [-v repl=`"] input-file > output-file
#       -v delim    delimiter, defaults to tab
#       -v repl     replacement char, defaults to ~

# e.g. gawk -v delim=; -v repl=` -f csv2delim.awk test.csv > test.txt

# abe 2-28-7
# abe 8-8-8 1.0 fixed empty fields, added replacement option
# abe 8-27-8 1.1 used split
# abe 8-27-8 1.2 inline rpl and "" = '
# abe 8-27-8 1.3 revert to 1.0 as it is much faster, split most of the time
# abe 8-29-8 1.4 better message if delim present

BEGIN {
    if (delim == "") delim = "\t"
    if (repl == "") repl = "~"
    print "csv2delim.awk v.m 1.4 run at " strftime() > "/dev/stderr" ###########################################
}

{
    #if ($0 ~ repl) {
    #   print "Replacement character " repl " is on line " FNR ":" lineIn ";" > "/dev/stderr"
    #}
    if ($0 ~ delim) {
        print "Temp delimiter character " delim " is on line " FNR ":" lineIn ";" > "/dev/stderr"
        print "    replaced by " repl > "/dev/stderr"
    }
    gsub(delim, repl)

    $0 = gensub(/([^,])\"\"/, "\\1'", "g")
#   $0 = gensub(/\"\"([^,])/, "'\\1", "g")  # not needed above covers all cases

    out = ""
    #for (i = 1;  i <= length($0);  i++)
    n = length($0)
    for (i = 1;  i <= n;  i++)
        if ((ch = substr($0, i, 1)) == "\"")
            inString = (inString) ? 0 : 1 # toggle inString
        else
            out = out ((ch == "," && ! inString) ? delim : ch)
    print out
}

END {
    print NR " records processed from " FILENAME " at " strftime() > "/dev/stderr"
}
```

#### test.csv

```
"first","second","third"
"fir,st","second","third"
"first","sec""ond","third"
" first ",sec   ond,"third"
"first" , "second","th  ird"
"first","sec;ond","third"
"first","second","th;ird"
1,2,3
,2,3
1,2,
,2,
1,,2
1,"2",3
"1",2,"3"
"1",,"3"
1,"",3
"","",""
"","""aiyn","oh"""
"""","""",""""
11,2~2,3
```

#### test.bat

```
rem test csv2delim
rem default is: -v delim={tab} -v repl=~
gawk                      -f csv2delim.awk test.csv > test.txt
gawk -v delim=;           -f csv2delim.awk test.csv > testd.txt
gawk -v delim=; -v repl=` -f csv2delim.awk test.csv > testdr.txt
gawk            -v repl=` -f csv2delim.awk test.csv > testr.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure whether this is the right way to do things. I would rather work on a csv file in which either all values are to quoted or none. Btw, awk allows regexes to be Field Separators. Check if that is useful.

Comment: I would also go for the regexp approach and try to let it match something like this ^"|","|"$  (this is a quick shot, you have of course to escape the ", I want to keep it simple)

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  ColumnCount = 0
  $0 = $0 ","                           # Assures all fields end with comma
  while($0)                             # Get fields by pattern, not by delimiter
  {
    match($0, / *"[^"]*" *,|[^,]*,/)    # Find a field with its delimiter suffix
    Field = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) # Get the located field with its delimiter
    gsub(/^ *"?|"? *,$/, "", Field)     # Strip delimiter text: comma/space/quote
    Column[++ColumnCount] = Field       # Save field without delimiter in an array
    $0 = substr($0, RLENGTH + 1)        # Remove processed text from the raw data
  }
}
```

Patterns that follow this one can access the fields in Column[].  ColumnCount indicates the number of elements in Column[] that were found.  If not all rows contain the same number of columns, Column[] contains extra data after Column[ColumnCount] when processing  the shorter rows.

This implementation is slow, but it appears to emulate the `FPAT`/`patsplit()` feature found in gawk >= 4.0.0 mentioned in a previous answer.

[Reference](http://backreference.org/2010/04/17/csv-parsing-with-awk/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with.  Any comments and/or better solutions would be appreciated.

```
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    f[++n] = $i
    if (substr(f[n],1,1)=="\"") {
      while (substr(f[n], length(f[n]))!="\"" || substr(f[n], length(f[n])-1, 1)=="\\") {
        f[n] = sprintf("%s,%s", f[n], $(++i))
      }
    }
  }
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "field #%d: %s\n", i, f[i]
  print "----------------------------------\n"
}
```

The basic idea is that I loop through the fields, and any field which starts with a quote but does not end with a quote gets the next field appended to it.

Comment: This looks more C-like.. Are we using the right tool for the right job? I am a novice in awk and can't think of any straight forward solutions though..

Comment: @Vijay Dev, novice means beginner, not expert.

Comment: Ah My English !! I wanted to say - 'I am a novice and <em>so</em> I can't think of any straight forward solutions'

Comment: FYI, this works, but you need "n=0" as a final line for it to function on a multi-line file properly.

Comment: Note that a valid field could be: `"""Jump"", he said!"`.  This will be split at the comma, but the character before is a double quote.  The script splits at the comma, even though it shouldn't as the comma is embedded inside a quoted field.  An odd number of double quotes preceding the comma indicates end-of-field; an even number does not.

Answer (score 0):

Perl has the Text::CSV_XS module which is purpose-built to handle the quoted-comma weirdness.
Alternately try the Text::CSV module.

`perl -MText::CSV_XS -ne 'BEGIN{$csv=Text::CSV_XS->new()} if($csv->parse($_)){@f=$csv->fields();for $n (0..$#f) {print "field #$n: $f[$n]\n"};print "---\n"}' file.csv`

Produces this output:

```
field #0: one
field #1: two
field #2: three, four
field #3: five
---
field #0: six, seven
field #1: eight
field #2: nine
---
```

Here's a human-readable version.
Save it as parsecsv, chmod +x, and run it as "parsecsv file.csv"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV_XS;
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new();
open(my $data, '<', $ARGV[0]) or die "Could not open '$ARGV[0]' $!\n";
while (my $line = <$data>) {
    if ($csv->parse($line)) {
        my @f = $csv->fields();
        for my $n (0..$#f) {
            print "field #$n: $f[$n]\n";
        }
        print "---\n";
    }
}
```

You may need to point to a different version of perl on your machine, since the Text::CSV_XS module may not be installed on your default version of perl.

```
Can't locate Text/CSV_XS.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/gnu/lib/perl5/5.6.1/i686-linux /home/gnu/lib/perl5/5.6.1 /home/gnu/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.6.1/i686-linux /home/gnu/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.6.1 /home/gnu/lib/perl5/site_perl .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

If none of your versions of Perl have Text::CSV_XS installed, you'll need to:
`sudo apt-get install cpanminus`
`sudo cpanm Text::CSV_XS`