# how to use "," as field delimiter

Tags: awk, field, delimiter

i have a file like this:

```
"1","ab,c","def"
```

so only use comma a field delimiter will get wrong result, so i want to use "," as field delimiter, i tried like this:

```
awk -F "," '{print $0}' file
```

or like this:

```
awk -F "","" '{print $0}' file
```

or like this:

```
awk -F '","' '{print $0}' file
```

but the result is incorrect, don't know how to include "" as part of the field delimiter itself,

Comment: `-F '","'` seems to work (as in split at literal `","`, not magically becoming a ‘quote-aware parser’). How are you testing it if you only `print $0`, though?!

Comment: You don't want to use `"` as part of the field delimiter, you want your program to "lex" (as in: to divide into separate "tokens") respecting quotation marks, that's a different problem!

Comment: See [Escaping separator within double quotes, in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7804673/3832970)

Comment: '","' do not work, $0 in my post is a  typo,

Comment: `echo '"1","ab,c","def"' | awk -F '","' '{print $1}'` works for me and prints `"1` correctly. If you want to parse a CSV file with quotes, consider not reinventing the wheel and use some existing parser or library? My 5 min google serach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138363/can-awk-deal-with-csv-file-that-contains-comma-inside-a-quoted-field https://coderwall.com/p/mplocg/simple-quote-comma-csv-parsing-in-awk https://github.com/geoffroy-aubry/awk-csv-parser . But really use csvtool

Comment: ok, didn't realize there is existing tools,

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle GNU awk, you could use `FPAT`:

```
$ echo '"1","ab,c","def"' |        # echo outputs with double quotes
gawk '                             # use GNU awk
BEGIN {
    FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"    # because FPAT
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)             # loop all fields
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i)        # remove leading and trailing double quotes
    print $2                       # output for example the second field
}'
```

Output:

```
ab,c
```

`FPAT` cannot handle `RS` inside the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting seems misdirected anyway. How about this instead?

```sh
awk '/^".*"$/{ sub(/^\"/, ""); sub(/\"$/, ""); gsub(/\",\", ",") }1'
```

The proper solution to handling CSV files with quoting in them is to use a language which has an actual CSV parser. My thoughts go to Python, which includes a [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) in its standard library.

Answer (score 0):

In GNU `AWK`

```
{print $0}
```

does print whole line, if no change were made original line is `print`ed, no matter what field separator you set you will get original lines if only action is `print $0`. Use `$1=$1` to trigger string rebuild.

If you must do it via `FS` AT ANY PRICE, then you might do it as follows: let `file.txt` content be

```
"1","ab,c","def"
```

then

```
BEGIN{FS="\x22,?\x22?"}{$1=$1;print $0}
```

output

```
 1 ab,c def
```

Note leading space (`ab,c` is $3). Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator is literal `"` (`\x22`, `"` is 22(hex) in ASCII) followed by zero or one (`?`) `,` followed by zero or one (`?`) literal `"` (`\x22`). `$1=$1` trigger line rebuilt as mentioned earlier. Disclaimer: this solution assume that you never have escaped `"` inside your string,

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*