# python csv: getting subset

Tags: python, csv

here is a snapshot of my csv:

```
alex    123f    1
harry   fwef    2
alex    sef 3
alex    gsdf    4
alex    wf35    6
harry   sdfsdf  3
```

i would like to get the subset of this data where the occurrence of anything in the first column (harry, alex) is at least 4. so i want the resulting data set to be:

```
alex    123f    1
alex    sef 3
alex    gsdf    4
alex    wf35    6
```

Comment: That's nice. What exactly is the question?

Comment: If you want to filter selected rows, you'll have to write some code.  Please post the code you wrote.  Hint: include an `if` statement in your code.  Another Hint: This is not `www.do_my_homework_for_me.com`.

Comment: this is not a "teach me your morals" forum and it is not a "we will answer your question only if it seems like it is not homework" forum.

Comment: In any language, an overview of a minimal complexity low memory usage solution would be: (1) read the file once, building a table mapping names to occurrence counts e.g. `{'alex': 4, 'harry': 2}`. (2) read the file again, writing only the records where the name occurs 4 or more times. Try that and ask again if you have problems.

Comment: "this is not a "teach me your morals" forum"?  What?  You're not doing any work asking us to do all the work for you.  We resent that.  We'll answer **specific** questions.  We won't do your work for you. We're not volunteer programmers.  We have jobs.  This is not a "moral" issue.  This is an "exploitation" issue.  We don't feel like being exploited by you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly, you cannot decide which rows are interesting until you've seen all rows (since the very last row might be the one turning some count from three to four and thereby making some previously seen rows interesting, for example;-).  So, unless your CSV file is horribly huge, suck it all into memory, first, as a list...:

```
import csv

with open('thefile.csv', 'rb') as f:
  data = list(csv.reader(f))
```

then, do the counting -- Python 2.7 has a better way, but assuming you're still on 2.6 like most of us...:

```
import collections
counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
for row in data:
    counter[row[0]] += 1
```

and finally do the selection loop...:

```
for row in data:
    if counter[row[0]] >= 4:
        print row
```

Of course, this prints each interesting row as a roughly-hewed list (with square brackets and quotes around the items), but it will be easy to format it in any way you might prefer.

Comment: @I___, yep, it will be just fine.  A typical modern machine has no less than a GB (a thousand megs), so it will have ample space to read in and process your seventy-megs file (even though the data typically takes up a bit more space in memory than it does on disk).

Comment: @I__: try it; it's only 10 lines of code and it won't break your computer if it runs out of memory ... if it does, then you can write some code to implement the outline that I gave you in a comment to your non-question.

Comment: hi alex, this is not working for me, it's returning the wrong subset

Comment: @I__, if your delimiter, as it appears, is a tab (rather than a comma, the default delimiter from which Comma Separated Variable files, aka CSV files, are named), of course you have to make you reader slightly different, e.g. `data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'))` rather than the default way I built it. Apart from that obvious issue, the code, applied to your example input file, gives the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

if Python is not a must

```
$ gawk '{b[$1]++;c[++d,$1]=$0}END{for(i in b){if(b[i]>=4){for(j=1;j<=d;j++){print c[j,i]}}}}' file
```

And yes, 70MB file is fine.

Comment: The first part appears to select all records which end with the digit 4 followed by optional spaces an/or tabs. The OP appears to want records for names which appear at least 4 times. Your solution **accidentally** produces the same output as the OP's required output. Add another record `tom pqrs 4`; your solution prints that, contrary to the OP's requirements.