# Save results to csv file with Python

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
  data = list(csv.reader(f))

import collections
counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
for row in data:
    counter[row[1]] += 1
for row in data:
    if counter[row[1]] >= 4:
      writer = csv.writer(open("test1.csv", "wb"))
      writer.writerows(row)
```

I am getting strange output! What is wrong with this code?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: Less than 24 hours ago you accepted the [answer that has this link in its content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339403/smallest-learning-curve-language-to-work-with-csv-files/3339430#3339430)!

Comment: I posted this before, but you may not have read it.

Seriously, since you're just beginning in Python, it might be a good idea to look through a tutorial and learn the basics of the language, rather than try to learn just the features you need and search for the answers on StackOverflow when you can't find something. It'll take more time, sure, but you'll get a MUCH better understanding of the language.

Comment: See also: [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41585078/562769)

Comment: is there a good tutorial for writting csvs ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `csv.writer`:

```
import csv

with open('thefile.csv', 'rb') as f:
  data = list(csv.reader(f))

import collections
counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
for row in data:
    counter[row[0]] += 1


writer = csv.writer(open("/path/to/my/csv/file", 'w'))
for row in data:
    if counter[row[0]] >= 4:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 57):

I know the question is asking about your "csv" package implementation, but for your information, there are options that are much simpler — numpy, for instance.

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt('data.csv', (col1_array, col2_array, col3_array), delimiter=',')
```

---

(This answer posted 6 years later, for posterity's sake.)

In a different case similar to what you're asking about, say you have two columns like this:

```
names = ['Player Name', 'Foo', 'Bar']
scores = ['Score', 250, 500]
```

You could save it like this:

```
np.savetxt('scores.csv', [p for p in zip(names, scores)], delimiter=',', fmt='%s')
```

`scores.csv` would look like this:

```
Player Name,Score
Foo,250
Bar,500
```

Answer (score 10):

Use Pandas

```
   df.to_csv("your_preferred_name.csv")
```

Answer (score 6):

You can close files not csv.writer object, it should be:

```
f = open(fileName, "wb")
writer = csv.writer(f)
String[] entries = "first*second*third".split("*");
writer.writerows(entries)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy example would be something like:

```
writer = csv.writer(open("filename.csv", "wb"))
String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#");
writer.writerows(entries)
writer.close()
```

Comment: You can close files not csv.writer object, it should be
f = open(fileName, "wb")
writer = csv.writer(f)
String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#");
writer.writerows(entries)
f.close()

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it

```
 import csv
    file = open('???.csv', 'r')
    read = csv.reader(file)
    for column in read:
            file = open('???.csv', 'r')
            read = csv.reader(file)
            file.close()
            file = open('????.csv', 'a', newline='')
            write = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ",")
            write.writerow((, ))
            file.close()
```

Comment: The indentation is incorrect and why do you open the same file twice?

Answer (score -3):

***this will provide exact output***

```
import csv

import collections

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:

  data = list(csv.reader(f))

counter = collections.defaultdict(int)

for row in data:

    counter[row[0]] += 1

writer = csv.writer(open("file1.csv", 'w'))

for row in data:

    if counter[row[0]] >= 1:

        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This is just an exact copy of the accepted answer, but with no explanation and no formatting.