# How should I 'save all console outputs throughout my Game.py and write them to a new text file'?

Tags: python

I want to write all the Game.py console outputs to a new file every time its ran.

In my Game.py I run all the methods of my game through this

Game.py file:

```
class Game():
    def play():
        print("Some Text")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.play()
```

Just for clarity what I want is for the printed text to be saved to a .txt file.

game1.txt would have this inside
Some Text

I looked at some code before but I can't get my head around it, how would I do this with stdout?

Comment: To a file AND to stdout?

Comment: if you want to write to a csv check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345336/save-results-to-csv-file-with-python. Otherwise you should clarify to which format your output should be saved

Comment: @pythonic833 sorry, format is .txt

Comment: Then just check out the link I posted. That should be the answer to your question. csv and txt can be handled in the same way

Comment: @pythonic833 Alright, gonna take a look!

Comment: I'm not trying to parse in a particular line of text I think what I want is stdout to txt file so I don't think that'll work

Comment: @Carcigenicate Haven't used a helper before but what would message be. 
How would it be equal to prints output in the console and where do I define this method outside of my class or inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
class Game():
    def play():
        f = open("myfile.txt","w+")
        f.write("Some Text")
        # if you still want to print it
        print("Some Text")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.play()
```

Try to do that. If this works, then this is the answer. If this does not work, tell me.

I am writing `myfile.txt` with `open()` and a `w+` to write. Then I write in that what you want to write using `f.write()` and also a extra `print()` if you need it.

---

**EDIT**: Actually, if you have prints in multiple classes, try to open `myfile.txt` first and remember for the `Game` class to be the main class otherwise it will fail.

Comment: Not "it" to be exact. So when ran in console this will print Some Text and also create a file with only some text, now lets say I have many prints throughout my whole programme it wouldn't be very efficient to have to do this every time unless it does ofc... so I need something to intercept each print and then write it to file.

Comment: Well, if that's the case, I don't know, what about combining the prints to 1 single line?

Comment: Wouldn't work if I have prints in other classes I don't think, still not a bad answer if I were to be printing one or a couple lines but not all throughout my programme. This is something Like Logging I guess but logging prints and anything else to a file exactly as it appears when ran in console.