# Using awk or perl to extract specific columns from CSV (parsing)

Tags: perl, parsing, csv, awk

**Background** - I want to extract specific columns from a csv file. The csv file is comma delimited, uses double quotes as the text-qualifier (optional, but when a field contains special characters, the qualifier will be there - see example), and uses backslashes as the escape character. It is also possible for some fields to be blank.

---

**Example Input and Desired Output** - For example, I only want columns 1, 3, and 4 to be in the output file. The final extract of the columns from the csv file should match the format of the original file. No escape characters should be removed or extra quotes added and such.

*Input*

```
"John \"Super\" Doe",25,"123 ABC Street",123-456-7890,"M",A
"Jane, Mary","",132 CBS Street,333-111-5332,"F",B
"Smith \"Jr.\", Jane",35,,555-876-1233,"F",
"Lee, Jack",22,123 Sesame St,"","M",D
```

*Desired Output*

```
"John \"Super\" Doe","123 ABC Street",123-456-7890
"Jane, Mary",132 CBS Street,333-111-5332
"Smith \"Jr.\", Jane",,555-876-1233
"Lee, Jack",123 Sesame St,""
```

---

**Preliminary Script (awk)** - The following is a preliminary script I found that works for the most part, but does not work in one particular instance that I noticed and possibly more that I have not seen or thought of yet

```
#!/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{  OFS = FS = ","  }

/"/{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if($i ~ /^"[^"]+$/){
            for(x=i+1;x<=NF;x++){
                $i=$i","$x
                if($i ~ /"+$/){
                    z = x - (i + 1) + 1
                    for(y=i+1;y<=NF;y++)
                        $y = $(y + z)
                    break
                }
            }
            NF = NF - z
            i=x
        }
    }
print $1,$3,$4
}
```

The above seems to work well until it comes across a field that contains both escaped double quotes as well as a comma. In that case, the parsing will be off and the output will be incorrect.

---

**Question/Comments** - I have read that awk is not the best option for parsing through csv files, and perl is suggested. However, I do not know perl at all. I have found some examples of perl scripts, but they do not give the desired output I am looking for and I do not know how to edit the scripts easily for what I want.

As for awk, I am familiar with it and use the basic functionality of it occasionally, but I do not know a lot of the advanced functionality like some of the commands used in the script above. Is my desired output possible just by using awk? If so, would it be possible edit the script above to fix the issue I am having with it? Could someone explain line by line what exactly the script is doing?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The reason why perl is suggested over awk is because the former has the capability to do look-ahead/look-behind assertions in order to discriminate a field separator from an internal field value

Comment: @SiegeX - sorry, but you're way wrong. Perl is suggested over awk because there are 100% working, fully (or almost) debugged stable production quality CSV parsing modules on CPAN, so that you don't have to reinvent (poorly) the bicycle. Specifically, Text::CSV is usually considered a classic.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the prohibition against "extra quotes added" part? Also, are the quotes for fields obeying some 100% involatile standard rule for input file? (e.g. "**only** quote fields that contain spaces, commas, or quotes")?

Comment: @DVK, No, no such rule. It's random whether quotes are used or not.

Comment: @DVK - No, there is no reason to prohibit extra quotes added as ikegami mentioned. I just mentioned that to emphasize I wanted the output file to be as closely formatted to the original as possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not going to reinvent the [wheel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS).

```
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
   binary      => 1,
   escape_char => '\\',
   eol         => "\n",
});

my $fh_in  = \*STDIN;
my $fh_out = \*STDOUT;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh_in)) {
   $csv->print($fh_out, [ @{$row}[0,2,3] ])
      or die("".$csv->error_diag());
}

$csv->eof()
   or die("".$csv->error_diag());
```

Output:

```
"John \"Super\" Doe","123 ABC Street",123-456-7890
"Jane, Mary","132 CBS Street",333-111-5332
"Smith \"Jr.\", Jane",,555-876-1233
"Lee, Jack","123 Sesame St",
```

It adds quotes around addresses that didn't have any already, but since some addresses already have quotes around them, you obviously can handle that.

---

Reinventing the wheel:

```
my $field = qr/"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|[^"\\,]*/s;
while (<>) {
   my @fields = /^($field),$field,($field),($field),/
      or die;
   print(join(',', @fields), "\n");
}
```

Output:

```
"John \"Super\" Doe","123 ABC Street",123-456-7890
"Jane, Mary",132 CBS Street,333-111-5332
"Smith \"Jr.\", Jane",,555-876-1233
"Lee, Jack",123 Sesame St,""
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. Unfortunately, I am not able to use your first solution since the machine I am using does not have the Text::CSV_XS module and I am not able to install it.

The second (reinvented) solution  works for what I need. However, the only problem is the part where it specifies which columns to print out. Is there a way to specify which columns similar to the first solution where you can just list the column numbers? Potentially, my csv file can have hundreds of columns and I need to be able to easily change which columns to parse out.

Comment: @yousir - you cn use Text::SCV instead. It's pure Perl

Comment: @yousir, You did not say why you cannot install it, so we can neither help you install it or find a workaround if we don't know what needs to be worked around.

Comment: @yousir, I didn't make it so you could pick other columns because that wasn't your question. But really, it's trivial to build the pattern dynamically to pick other columns.

Comment: @ikegami - Sorry, I should have been more clear. I was trying to generalize the concept. How would I generate that list with perl? For example, I have a variable "columns" that lists exactly which columns to print out in the following format "1,3,4,6,99,etc". But I am having trouble incorporating it into your script.

Comment: @ikegami - I cannot install any modules (as well as Text::CSV mentioned by DVK) because I do not control the machine. Its a strict environment and it is unlikely for me to be able to request the module to be added. If it helps, the only thing that is listed when I run 'instmodsh' on the machine (Solaris 10), only "Perl" is listed.

Comment: @yousir, There's no difference between a module and a script, so that's not true. You don't need any special permission to install a module.

Comment: @yousir, The problem with reinventing the wheel is that now you expect me to maintain that wheel. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: @ikegami - Unless I was following the wrong instructions, I indeed do need additional privileges to install a a module from CPAN. Regardless, I was able to find a workaround way to "install" Text:CSV as DVK suggested and utilize your first script to achieve what I wanted. I simply had to put CSV.pm and CSV_PP.pm from the Text:CSV source in a folder named "Text" in the working directory of the script.

Comment: @yousir, You insist special permissions are required in the same paragraph as you explain how you didn't need special permissions... (To be clear, you don't need special permissions when using the regular tools either. Modules can be installed to any directory.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest **python** `csv` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
rdr = csv.reader(open('input.csv'), escapechar='\\')
wtr = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w'), escapechar='\\', doublequote=False)
for row in rdr:
    wtr.writerow(row[0:1]+row[2:4])
```

---

#### output.csv

```
John \"Super\" Doe,123 ABC Street,123-456-7890
"Jane, Mary",132 CBS Street,333-111-5332
"Smith \"Jr.\", Jane",,555-876-1233
"Lee, Jack",123 Sesame St,
```

Comment: Removing double quotes where they exist is worse than adding some where they aren't any.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will extract the required fields(e.g., first, third and fourth) separated by delimiter ',' from sample.csv file and displays the output in the console.
**cut -f1,3,4 -d',' sample.txt**
If you want to store the output in a new csv file, then redirect the output to a file as below
**cut -f1,3,4 -d',' sample.txt > newSample.csv**

Answer (score 0):

Before I post, I see now that this is an old question bumped by an already deleted answer, however, I thought I would still use the opportunity to show off [Tie::Array::CSV](http://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aCSV) which make CSV file manipulation as easy as working with Perl arrays. Full disclosure: I'm the author.

Anyway here is the script. The OP's data required changing the escape character and Perl indexes arrays starting at 0, but other than that this should be quite readable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::Array::CSV;

my $opts = { text_csv => { escape_char => '\\' } };

tie my @input,  'Tie::Array::CSV', 'data', $opts or die "Cannot open file 'data': $!";
tie my @output, 'Tie::Array::CSV', 'out',  $opts or die "Cannot open file 'out': $!";

for my $row (@input) {
  my @slice = @{ $row }[0,2,3];
  push @output, \@slice;
}
```

That said, I think that last loop doesn't loose too much readability if I convert it to the (IMO) more impressive form:

```
push @output, [ @{$_}[0,2,3] ] for @input;
```

Answer (score 0):

[csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/#) is a tool that handles csv files and allows such operations (among other features).

see [csvcut](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/scripts/csvcut.html). Its command line interface is compact and it handles the multitude of csv formats (tsv, other delimiters, encodings, escape chars etc.)

What you asked for can be done using:

```
csvcut --columns 0,2,3 input.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some mistakes hopefully corrected now.

```
awk '{sub(/y",""/,"y\42")sub(/,2.|,3./,"")sub(/,".",.*/,"")}1' file

"John \"Super\" Doe","123 ABC Street",123-456-7890
"Jane, Mary",132 CBS Street,333-111-5332
"Smith \"Jr.\", Jane",,555-876-1233
"Lee, Jack",123 Sesame St,""
```

Comment: Output of 2nd line doesn't comply with OP's.

Answer (score 0):

GNU **awk** solution. Just using the wheel as a wheel. You can define what fields should look like using **FPAT**, like this:

```
$ awk -vFPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]*"' -vOFS=, '{print $1, $3, $4}' file
```

which results in:

```
"John \"Super\" Doe","123 ABC Street",123-456-7890
"Jane, Mary",132 CBS Street,333-111-5332
"Smith \"Jr.\",35,555-876-1233
"Lee, Jack",123 Sesame St,""
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
[^,]+           # 1 or more occurrences of anything that's not a comma, 
|               # OR
"[^"]*"         # 0 or more characters unequal to '"' enclosed by '"'
```

Read about FPAT in the [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content)

Now, walking you through **your** script. Basically it tries to rewrite what your fields look like. At first, you split by ",", which obviously causes some problems. Next, it looks for fields that are not properly closed by a '"'.

```
BEGIN{OFS=FS =","}                        # set field sep (FS) and output field 
                                          #   sep to ,
/"/{                                      # for each line matching '"'
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                   # loop through fields 1 to NF
        if($i ~ /^"[^"]+$/){              # IF field $i start with '"', followed by
                                          #   non-quotes
            for(x=i+1;x<=NF;x++){         # loop through ALL following fields
                $i=$i","$x                # concatenate field $i with ALL following 
                                          #   fields, separated by ","
                if($i ~ /"+$/){           # IF field $i ends with '"'
                    z = x - (i + 1) + 1   # z is index of field we're looking at next
                    for(y=i+1;y<=NF;y++)  
                        $y = $(y + z)     # change contents of following fields to 
                                          #   contents of field, z steps further
                                          #   down the line
                    break                 # break out of for(x) loop
                }
            }
            NF = NF - z                   # reset number of fields
            i=x                           # continue loop for(i) at index x
        }
    }
 print $1,$3,$4
}
```

You script fails on this input line:

```
"Smith \"Jr.\", Jane",35,,555-876-1233,"F",
```

simply because `$i ~ /^"[^"]+$/` fails on $1.

I hope you agree with me that rewriting the fields like this can be tricky. More than that, it's like "O, I like awk, but I'm going to use it like C/perl/python." Using FPAT is a shorter solution, to say the least.