# Recognizing columns with quoted spaces

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with the following content:

```
"aaa" "aaa bbb" "c cc  c" "ddd"
```

I'm looking for command that will show me specified column.

I try to use:

```
awk '{print $1}'
```

But it doesn't work properly if there is a space char in doublequetoes like "c cc  c".

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: so how do you think awk recognizes columns?

Comment: Hi Karoly, I know how it works(it uses spaces) and I  know that  it is possible to define own field seperator. I don't  know only how to define  such separator.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+define+own+field+seperator (sic!)

Comment: Karoly, don't be so mean. Pasting link to google you could answer on all question on stackoverflow, but it doesn't help anyone.

Comment: That's why we expect quality questions which cannot be answered by simply googling it. Creating duplicate questions doesn't help anyone.... and as a sidenote, searching is an immensely important and useful skill, something that all beginners have to learn. There's nothing mean about showing someone how to find something.

Comment: @tripleee it isn't duplicate from [Parse a csv using awk and ignoring commas inside a field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205431/parse-a-csv-using-awk-and-ignoring-commas-inside-a-field), they are using [AWK CSV Parser](http://lorance.freeshell.org/csv/)

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. The fact that your field separator isn't a comma means your input isn't strictly CSV, but the problem and the solutions are fundamentally the same regardless. This is a very common question; if you don't like that particular duplicate, please do suggest a different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `FPAT` variable in **gnu-awk** to break the columns based on a regex:

```
s='"aaa" "aaa bbb" "c cc  c" "ddd"'

awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "Field %d:: <%s>\n", i, $i}' <<< "$s"
Field 1:: <"aaa">
Field 2:: <"aaa bbb">
Field 3:: <"c cc  c">
Field 4:: <"ddd">
```

`-v FPAT='"[^"]+"'` will set each field value between 2 double quotes.

Comment: Nice one. Especially the `FPAT` variable.

Comment: Thanks for help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

A solution using traditional `awk`

```
echo '"aaa" "aaa bbb" "c cc  c" "ddd"' | 
awk -c -F "^\"|\"[ \t]+\"|\"$" '{
    for(i=2; i<=NF-1; i++) 
        printf "\"%s\"\n", $i 
}'
```

you get:

```
"aaa"
"aaa bbb"
"c cc  c"
"ddd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue! Use the [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV) module:

```
perl -MText::CSV -lwe '
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new({sep_char => " "}) or die Text::CSV->error_diag;
    open my $FH, "<", "input.txt" or die $!;
    while (my $row = $csv->getline($FH)) {
        print $row->[3];
    }'
```