# Remove duplicate column from csv in ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, awk, sed

CSV data format

```
1st Format

name,email,mobile,email
a,a@test.com,1234567890,a@test.com

2nd Format
name,email,"mobile,number",email
a,a@test.com,1234567890,a@test.com

3rd Format
name,email,"mobile number",email
a,a@test.com,1234567890,a@test.com
```

In my above data format email is duplicate in header so I only want to keep first column value for email and second email data with header should be deleted from file.

I have tied this but it;s not working properly

```
awk  -F'","' 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(!($i in v)){ v[$i];t[i]}}{s=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i in t)s=s sprintf("%s,",$i);if(s){sub(/,$/,"",s);print s}} ' input.csv > output.csv
```

Please suggest script command for the same

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in your question which is highly encouraged on SO. You could also use search functionality of SO to look for answers(not my downvote btw).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have updated my question with my effort

Comment: Since efforts are added I have voted to reopen this question, but your samples are not clear so kindly do add more clear samples in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Handling CSV with AWK is more complex than `-F","`, because a value could contain a comma.

Comment: @rethab yes value can have comma

Comment: Take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17287068/1080523

Comment: @rethab this is not solving my issue

Comment: I'd use `csvcut` from cvskit.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is probably not the most practical tool for manipulating CSV files. There are many others.

Here are a few examples, with your data

- **csvtool** (`sudo apt install csvtool`)

```
$ for f in [123].csv; do echo $f; csvtool col 1-3 "$f"; echo; done
1.csv
name,email,mobile
a,a@test.com,1234567890

2.csv
name,email,"mobile,number"
a,a@test.com,1234567890

3.csv
name,email,mobile number
a,a@test.com,1234567890
```

- **csvcut** (`sudo apt install csvkit`)

```
$ for f in [123].csv; do echo $f; csvcut -C 4 "$f"; echo; done
1.csv
name,email,mobile
a,a@test.com,1234567890

2.csv
name,email,"mobile,number"
a,a@test.com,1234567890

3.csv
name,email,mobile number
a,a@test.com,1234567890
```

- Perl's **Text::CSV** (`sudo apt install libtext-csv-perl`)
  (This would probably be better suited for more complex needs, and should be in a more readable script file)

```
$ for f in [123].csv; do echo $f; perl -MText::CSV -lne 'BEGIN{$csv=Text::CSV_XS->new()} if ($csv->parse($_)) {$csv->print(*STDOUT, [ ($csv->fields)[0..2] ]);}' "$f"; echo; done
1.csv
name,email,mobile
a,a@test.com,1234567890

2.csv
name,email,mobile,number
a,a@test.com,1234567890

3.csv
name,email,mobile number
a,a@test.com,1234567890
```

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV is well-formed, try

```sh
sed 's/^\("\([^"]|""\)*"|\[^",]*\),\("\([^"]|""\)*"|\[^",]*\),\("\([^"]|""\)*"|\[^",]*\),\("\([^"]|""\)*"|\[^",]*\)$/\1,\3,\5/'
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/7xKlGU

The regex isn't particularly elegant but should work straightforwardly.  `"\([^"]\|""\)*"` matches a quoted field and `[^",]*` matches a field which isn't quoted.  This assumes that either a field in its entirety is quoted, or not at all, and that the escaping mechanism is doubling the double quotes which should be literal, as is the convention in most common CSV dialects.