# awk CSV parsing using FPAT result in wrong output

Tags: bash, awk

I need to parse some CSV and there is a limitation that it has to be awk/bash. The below is the best I got, but it returns

Ecology",Biology

but I would need "PhD, Ecology". Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
echo '6,John Smith,"PhD, Ecology",Biology Department' |
    awk 'BEGIN{FPAT = "\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]*"} {print $3}'
```

The similar question here did not help me: [Parse a csv using awk and ignoring commas inside a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205431/parse-a-csv-using-awk-and-ignoring-commas-inside-a-field)

```
awk version 20200816
```

MacOS.

Comment: I get proper output with `GNU Awk 5.1.0`

Comment: What is your version of awk? `awk --version`

Comment: Hm.. I'm on Mac, `awk version 20200816`. Will check if I can get a different version.

Comment: same command with `gawk` instead works fine, thanks a lot for the comment!!!

Comment: Looks you don't have **GNU awk**, that's the reason. Try to install GNU version with homebrew: `brew install gawk`

Comment: @M3RS `awk version <date>` is the typical (and full) response to the `--version` flag from [onetrueawk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk). In contrast, [GNU Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) responds to `--version` with a few paragraphs of text, the first one containing a line with something like `GNU Awk <version>, API <version>, PMA <version>, (GNU MPFR <version>, GNU MP <version>)`, followed by another one with a copyright notice.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't use `GNU awk`.

You need to install `GNU` version with [`homebrew`](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install gawk
```