# Escaping separator within double quotes, in awk

Tags: awk, delimiter, double-quotes, separator

I am using awk to parse my data with "," as separator as the input is a csv file. However, there are "," within the data which is escaped by double quotes ("...").

Example

```
filed1,filed2,field3,"field4,FOO,BAR",field5
```

How can i ignore the comma "," within the the double quote so that I can parse the output correctly using awk? I know we can do this in excel, but how do we do it in awk?

Comment: For a very comprehensive description look here: >[http://backreference.org/2010/04/17/csv-parsing-with-awk/](http://web.archive.org/web/20120531065332/http://backreference.org/2010/04/17/csv-parsing-with-awk/) (archive.org version) But this is not parsing, but cheating with regexp. For anything more complicated than the examples on the page you should use Perl/Python with a parser library like "csv" for Python.

Comment: Great articles on Text:CSV parsing using perl:

http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/parsing_csv.html

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001 for parsing CSV with awk.

Answer (score 30):

It's easy, with *GNU awk 4*:

```
zsh-4.3.12[t]% awk '{ 
 for (i = 0; ++i <= NF;)
   printf "field %d => %s\n", i, $i
 }' FPAT='([^,]+)|("[^"]+")' infile
field 1 => filed1
field 2 => filed2
field 3 => field3
field 4 => "field4,FOO,BAR"
field 5 => field5
```

Adding some comments as per OP requirement.

From the [GNU awk manual on "Defining fields by content](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html#Splitting-By-Content):

> The value of FPAT should be a string that provides a regular
>   expression. This regular expression describes the contents of each
>   field. In the case of CSV data as presented above, each field is
>   either “anything that is not a comma,” or “a double quote, anything
>   that is not a double quote, and a closing double quote.” If written as
>   a regular expression constant, we would have `/([^,]+)|("[^"]+")/`. Writing this as a string
>   requires us to escape the double quotes, leading to:
>
> `FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"`

Using `+` twice, this does not work properly for empty fields, but it can be fixed as well:

> As written, the regexp used for FPAT requires that each field contain at least one character. A straightforward modification (changing the first ‘`+`’ to ‘`*`’) allows fields to be empty:
>
> `FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"`

Comment: This is brilliant @DimitreRadoulov. You have a very thorough knowledge of `gawk` :-). I have used your suggestion over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8949920/970195) and have made a reference to this answer. Hope thats ok. +1

Comment: Jumping across from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8949920/970195), this solution doesn't appear to work for my data. In fact it splits the fields based on the spaces (default value of FS is a space), rather than the regex specified by FPAT. Adding `FS=","` seems to make awk ignore `FPAT` altogether, as it doesn't escape the quoted field with embedded comma

Comment: Hi @chrisbunney, could you please confirm that you're using *GNU awk 4*? Why are you setting FS?

Comment: Apparently I'm not using GNU awk 4: `gawk -W version: GNU Awk 3.1.7`. Although you specified GNU awk 4, I didn't realise this functionality might not be present in earlier versions. I was fiddling around, which is why I set FS, to see what happened

Comment: The builtin variable *FPAT* was introduced in *GNU awk 4*. I've just posted a *Perl* solution in your original thread.

Comment: Mac users can do `brew install gawk` and use `gawk` in place of `awk`.

Comment: Doe this solution work for mawk ? I tried in gawk and it's working but not working in mawk.

Answer (score 12):

FPAT works when there are newlines and commas inside the quoted fields, but not when there are double quotes, like this:

```
field1,"field,2","but this field has ""escaped"" quotes"
```

You can use a simple wrapper program I wrote called csvquote to make data easy for awk to interpret, and then restore the problematic special characters, like this:

```
csvquote inputfile.csv | awk -F, '{print $4}' | csvquote -u
```

See https://github.com/dbro/csvquote for code and docs

Comment: Hi @DBro
Double-doublequotes can be accounted for expanding the FPAT regexp a little bit:`BEGIN { FPAT = "(\"([^\"]|\"\")*\")|([^,\"]*)" }`

Answer (score 0):

Fully fledged CSV parsers such as Perl's `Text::CSV_XS` are purpose-built to handle that kind of weirdness.

Suppose you only want to print the 4th field:

`perl -MText::CSV_XS -lne 'BEGIN{$csv=Text::CSV_XS->new()} if($csv->parse($_)){ @f=$csv->fields(); print "\"$f[3]\"" }' file`

The input line is split into array `@f`
Field 4 is `$f[3]` since Perl starts indexing at 0

I provided more explanation of `Text::CSV_XS` within my answer here:  [parse csv file using gawk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314384/parse-csv-file-using-gawk/33380831#33380831)