# Compare two large csv files by field and save output

Tags: unix, awk

I'm trying to compare two very large csv files and compare them by a free text field in both. I've tried using awk, e.g.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$2]++;next} a[$2]' table1.csv table2.csv > duplicates.csv
```

but the output csv file isn't properly formatted, probably because the free text field contains commas. I'd like to save the entire duplicate row in table1 in the duplicate table. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Parsing a CSV is hard with AWK. How are fields with commas quoted or escaped?

Comment: They're simply quoted, and no spaces between commas and quotes between fields. I can read data in python/pandas just fine, but I was wondering if there was a nice one-liner out there.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output? It would be helpful.

Comment: You may have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220854/source-file-delimiter-issue/20227644#20227644

Comment: If you are using Gnu Awk version 4, you could use the `FPAT` variable.. See: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content

Comment: For earlier versions of awk, this page looks promising: http://backreference.org/2010/04/17/csv-parsing-with-awk/

Comment: Perl's `Text::CSV` or `Text::CSV_XS` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Did I understood right you need something like:

```
$ more filea fileb
::::::::::::::
filea
::::::::::::::
1,a
2,b
3,c
::::::::::::::
fileb
::::::::::::::
1,d
x,e
3,f
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    while (getline a < "filea" && getline b < "fileb") {
        split(a, aa, ",")
        split(b, bb, ",")
        if (aa[1] == bb[1]) {
            print a, b
        }
    }
}'
1,a 1,d
3,c 3,f
```