# how to extract a field containing delimiter from file using cut command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, cut

In Unix, suppose a file contains 5 fields & data such as:

```
"112233"|"Roshan"|"25"|" FAX 022 3987789 \| TEL 77766288892 \| abc "|"Male"
```

need to extract 4th field. using below

```
column_value=`echo $line | cut -f4 -d'|'
```

This only gives us - `" FAX 022 3987789 \`

but need `" FAX 022 3987789 \| TEL 77766288892 \| abc "` as 4th column value.

Effective delimiter should be -

> "|"

Comment: `cut` is not the right tool. You need a CSV parser

Comment: More to the point, reading the value into a variable `$line` is probably the wrong approach (and if you really do, use `read -r` and quote `"$line"` everywhere).

Answer (score 1):

`cut` is not the *right* tool for the job when it involves a multi-character de-limiter needed for parsing input string/file.

You can use [GNU Awk with FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) which defines how each field in a record should look like. You can write `FPAT` as a regular expression constant in which case something like below should work.

```
FPAT = "(\"[^\"]+\")"
```

Using this in the `Awk` command,

```
line='"112233"|"Roshan"|"25"|" FAX 022 3987789 \| TEL 77766288892 \| abc "|"Male"'
awk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "(\"[^\"]+\")"
}{print $4}' <<<"$line"
```

produces an output as

```
" FAX 022 3987789 \| TEL 77766288892 \| abc "
```

[Regular Expression - Test results](https://regex101.com/r/16hSpy/1)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804673/escaping-separator-within-double-quotes-in-awk

Answer (score 0):

you can add the two extra fields as follows

```
echo $line | cut -f 4,5,6 -d\|
```

alternatively you could use sed to replace the "|" delimiter with a different char (for example a tab)

```
echo $line | sed s/\"\|\"/\t/g | cut -f 4
```