# split text with fields and text delimiters

Tags: python, linux, shell, scripting, grep

Example line:

```
"1","Point 1","value1,value2,value3","value1: funtion1**\n**value2: function2","UUID=12345","description"
```

I want to extract column 1, column 2 and column 5.

- I cant use comma, since col3 has multiple comma.
- Column 4 contains multiple new line`\n` hence can't reach column 5(`UUID`).

We can achieve this by opening a csv file with excel, just need to select field delimiter and text delimiter. Is it possible with scripting?

You can download file with [this link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kRMgrmpdRcJBQE4-Au6kX8Zcl4mfc0dg?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you post your CSV? And the Example line is that a list or a string object?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804673/escaping-separator-within-double-quotes-in-awk

Comment: Cant you do it with python [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: I checked previous and mentioned articles. Few `uniq` things about this problem: multiple comma, multiple new lines and text delimiter as well which are not present in any of the article. To understand the problem clearly, please check mentioned link and open a csv file in excel. Its a one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you wanna do, using the following python:

```
import csv
with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
     for row in reader:
         for i, cell in enumerate(row):
            print("Cell %d: %s" % (i, cell))
```

you can get each column regardless on if they contain the delimiter or new lines. Output:

```
Cell 0: 1
Cell 1: Point 1
Cell 2: value1,value2,value3
Cell 3: value1: funtion1**\n**value2: function2
Cell 4: UUID=12345
Cell 5: description
```

Now, I opened your linked xlsx and saved as csv with LibreOffice, the code handles the new lines:

```
Cell 0: 1
Cell 1: point1
Cell 2: value1, value2,value3
Cell 3: Line1

Line2.

Line3.
Cell 4: UUID=123545
time=123seconds

Start time: x

End time: y
Cell 5: 1234
```

The raw csv contents were (note that although they represent a single *row* they do actually span multiple *lines* in the file):

```
1,point1,"value1, value2,value3","Line1

Line2.

Line3.","UUID=123545
time=123seconds

Start time: x

End time: y",1234
```

Let me know if the above snippet can handle your data but if they are indeed CSV format, it should be able to read the cells properly

Answer (score 0):

If the example line is a string. the below snippet should help.

```
s = """"1","Point 1","value1,value2,value3","value1: funtion1**\n**value2: function2","UUID=12345","description"
I """

val = [i.strip('"') for i in s.split('","')]
print(val)
print(val[4])     #use index to get element
```

**Output:**

```
['1', 'Point 1', 'value1,value2,value3', 'value1: funtion1**\n**value2: function2', 'UUID=12345', 'description"\nI ']
UUID=12345
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: this solution is simple, but highly dependent on the format being consistent.
Assuming there is no spacing in between the quotation marks and commas, you could separate them by `","`:

```
#input string
s = '"1","Point 1","value1,value2,value3","value1: funtion1**\n**value2: function2","UUID=12345","description"' 

# remove quotation marks and whitespace from edges, then split string into tuple
cols = s.strip('" ').split('","')
```

Now you can extract your columns, eg 5th column is `cols[4]`:

```
>> cols[4]
'UUID=12345'
```