# Extract specific columns from delimited file using Awk

Tags: unix, csv, awk

Sorry if this is too basic. I have a csv file where the columns have a header row  (v1, v2, etc.). I understand that to extract columns 1 and 2, I have to do: `awk -F "," '{print $1 "," $2}' infile.csv > outfile.csv`. But what if I have to extract, say, columns 1 to 10, 20 to 25, and 30, 33? As an addendum, is there any way to extract directly with the header names rather than with column numbers?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to do ranges in awk. You could do a for loop, but you would have to add handling to filter out the columns you don't want. It's probably easier to do this:

```
awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$30,$33}' infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

something else to consider - and this faster and more concise:

```
cut -d "," -f1-10,20-25,30-33 infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

As to the second part of your question, I would probably write a script in perl that knows how to handle header rows, parsing the columns names from stdin or a file and then doing the filtering. It's probably a tool I would want to have for other things. I am not sure about doing in a one liner, although I am sure it can be done.

Comment: Many thanks. Cut is what I need, I guess. This wouldn't work with the headers, by any chance?

Comment: I was just about to suggest `cut`, but Cliff got here first.

Comment: Note that in the general case of a CSV file with quoted strings, you can have non-delimiting commas in the data fields, which will cause the cut & awk solutions to fail.

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned by @Tom, the cut and awk approaches actually don't work for CSVs with quoted strings. An alternative is a module for python that provides the command line tool csvfilter. It works like cut, but properly handles CSV column quoting:

```
csvfilter -f 1,3,5 in.csv > out.csv
```

If you have python (and you should), you can install it simply like this:

```
pip install csvfilter
```

Please take note that the column indexing in csvfilter starts with 0 (unlike awk, which starts with $1). More info at https://github.com/codeinthehole/csvfilter/

Answer (score 4):

Other languages have short cuts for ranges of field numbers, but not awk, you'll  have to write your code as your fear ;-)

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} { print $1, $2, $3, $4 ..... $30, $33}' infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

There is no direct function in awk to use field names as column specifiers.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It does indeed. Thanks for the confirmation :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can use a for-loop to address a field with *$i*:

```
ls -l | awk '{for(i=3 ; i<8 ; i++) {printf("%s\t", $i)} print ""}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Others have answered your earlier question. For this:

> As an addendum, is there any way to extract directly with the header names rather than with column numbers?

I haven't tried it, but you could store each header's index in a hash and then use that hash to get its index later on.

```
for(i=0;i<$NF;i++){
    hash[$i] = i;
}
```

Then later on, use it:

```
j = hash["header1"];
print $j;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Tabulator](https://github.com/stefan-schroedl/tabulator) is a set of unix command line tools to work with csv files that have header lines. Here is an example to extract columns by name from a file `test.csv:`

```
name,sex,house_nr,height,shoe_size
arthur,m,42,181,11.5
berta,f,101,163,8.5
chris,m,1333,175,10
don,m,77,185,12.5
elisa,f,204,166,7
```

Then `tblmap -k name,height test.csv` produces

```
name,height
arthur,181
berta,163
chris,175
don,185
elisa,166
```

Answer (score 2):

If Perl is an option:

`perl -F, -lane 'print join ",",@F[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,19,20,21,22,23,24,29,32]'`

`-a` autosplits line into `@F` fields array.  Indices start at 0 (not 1 as in awk)
`-F,` field separator is ,

If your CSV file contains commas within quotes, fully fledged CSV parsers such as Perl's `Text::CSV_XS` are purpose-built to handle that kind of weirdness.

`perl -MText::CSV_XS -lne 'BEGIN{$csv=Text::CSV_XS->new()} if($csv->parse($_)){@f=$csv->fields();print (join ",",@f[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,19,20,21,22,23,24,29,32])}'`

I provided more explanation within my answer here:  [parse csv file using gawk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314384/parse-csv-file-using-gawk/33380831#33380831)

Answer (score 1):

Not using awk but the simplest way I was able to get this done was to just use [csvtool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/csvtool.1.html). I had other use cases as well to use csvtool and it can handle the quotes or delimiters appropriately if they appear within the column data itself.

```
csvtool format '%(2)\n' input.csv
csvtool format '%(2),%(3),%(4)\n' input.csv
```

Replacing 2 with the column number will effectively extract the column data you are looking for.